# How can I handle SockJsMessageDeliveryException in Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

In my application logs I got:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=****; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsMessageDeliveryException: Failed to deliver message(s)
```

I tried creating custom handler:

```
    @MessageExceptionHandler({SockJsMessageDeliveryException.class})
    public void handle(SockJsMessageDeliveryException e) {
        log.error("Handled websocket exception: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

but it didn't caught this exception.
I also tried to overwrite SimpMessagingTemplate

```
public class SilentErrorSimpMessagingTemplate extends SimpMessagingTemplate {
    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    SilentErrorSimpMessagingTemplate(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        super(simpMessagingTemplate.getMessageChannel());
        simpMessagingTemplate.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void convertAndSendToUser(@NotNull String user, @NotNull String destination, @NotNull Object payload) throws MessagingException {
        try {
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, destination, payload);
        } catch (SockJsMessageDeliveryException e) {
            log.error("Socket send error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to handle this error when websocket session was closed to not trigger my monitoring alarms. Any ideas?